# how to scrape the span class text if there are span of same class name?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[inspect an image of a youtube screen][1]

I want to scrape the text of the highlighted span class. but the problem is the above span class has the same attribute as the below one, like both, have the same class name, so when I write my code with bs4 using find() it grabs only the text of the first span class. So please help me with this, (suggest in python)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCqDp.png

Comment: did you try the `findAll` method to get all elements with the same class?

Comment: This `soup.select("[id='metadata-line'] > span")[-1]` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

### How to get the meta "created ... ago" ?

As usual there is not only one approach, I would recommend you to look for the information as child element with `:nth-of-type()`.

```
soup.select("[id='metadata-line'] > span:nth-of-type(2)")
```

Select the parent element by its `id` and the second element in it of type `<span>`

This will give you a list of all elements that you have to loop, to get the each text:

```
for item in soup.select("[id='metadata-line'] > span:nth-of-type(2)"):
    print(item.get_text())
```

If you are still in a loop that goes over all search results might would use `select_one()` what would give you a single item instead a list and you can `get_text()` directly:

```
soup.select_one("[id='metadata-line'] > span:nth-of-type(2)").get_text()
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=data+science"

driver.get(url)
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

for item in soup.select("[id='metadata-line'] > span:nth-of-type(2)"):
    print(item.get_text())

driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
vor 5 Monaten
vor 2 Jahren
vor 1 Jahr
vor 2 Jahren
vor 1 Jahr
vor 7 Monaten
vor 8 Monaten
vor 2 Monaten
vor 1 Monat
vor 1 Jahr
vor 1 Jahr
vor 3 Wochen
vor 1 Monat
vor 1 Tag
vor 4 Monaten
vor 9 Monaten
vor 8 Monaten
vor 2 Monaten
vor 5 Monaten
vor 1 Jahr
vor 1 Jahr
vor 4 Wochen
```